# setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) not working in MapFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a map fragment that has expand and collapse functionality. So when I expand the map I would like to hide the LinearLayout and when I collapse I wanna show that layout.

But the is `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` not working. When I was debugging the app I can see that compiler reading that line but still not working.

Here is my XML file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:visibility="visible">

   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.korechi.roamioapp.MainActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main_left_hand" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosImageView
        android:id="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.korechi.seekerapp.MainActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main_left_hand" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewToggleBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_sharp_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/mapSnapBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mapSnapBtn" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="520dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.korechi.roamioapp.MainActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main_left_hand" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/speedROS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/totalAreaRos"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/totalAreaRos" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/rtkStat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rtkLED"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rtkLED" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/lidarStat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/lidarLED"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lidarLED" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/spreaderStat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/spreaderLED"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spreaderLED" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rtkLED"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_button"
        android:text="RTK"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lidarLED"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lidarLED" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lidarLED"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_button"
        android:text="LiDAR"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/roamIOLogo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/roamIOLogo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/cameraView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cameraView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLatitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="Latitude"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
                android:id="@+id/latitudeTextView"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textLatitude"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textLatitude" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLongitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:text="Longitude"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/latitudeTextView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/latitudeTextView" />

            <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
                android:id="@+id/longitudeTextView"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textLongitude"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textLongitude" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
                android:text="Heading"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textLongitude"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLongitude" />

            <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
                android:id="@+id/headingTextView"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textHeading"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textHeading" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAltitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                android:text="Altitude"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textLatitude"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textLatitude" />

            <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
                android:id="@+id/altitudeTextView"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="480dp"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/roamIOLogo" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsHelperTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/rapgPointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pointsHelperTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/pointsHelperTextView" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/waypointsCoveredTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rapgPointsTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/totalDistanceRos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rapgPointsTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/totalAreaRos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/totalDistanceRos"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/batteryInfoBtn"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/battery"
        android:text="Battery %"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/settingsBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/settingsBtn" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/programStatusTextView"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textviewshape"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/map"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/batteryIndicaterBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/batteryInfoBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/batteryInfoBtn" />

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/batteryPercentageTxtView"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/batteryIndicaterBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/batteryIndicaterBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/roamIOLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/romaio_logo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EStopBtn"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/e_stop"
        android:text="@string/estop"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/left_main_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/left_main_layout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsBtn"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gear"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/expand"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/left_main_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left_main_layout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/magnetBtn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_magnet_01"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/left_main_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/left_main_layout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearMapBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/map"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/expandMapBtn"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/expand_map"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/clearMapBtn"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/clearMapBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mapSnapBtn"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/map"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveMapBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:text="Save Heat Map"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/viewToggleBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewToggleBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spreaderLED"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rounded_button"
        android:text="Spreader"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/rtkLED"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/rtkLED" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="640dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_frag_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_main_layout"
        android:layout_width="399dp"
        android:layout_height="396dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_side_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <com.korechi.roamioapp.Views.VirtualJoystickView
                android:id="@+id/left_virtual_joystick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code Where I was calling `setVisibility()` function

```
  case R.id.expandMapBtn:
                mVib.vibrate(50);
                storageAccess.logMessage("Expand button click");
                expandMapBtn.startAnimation(myAnim);
                constraintMap.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintMap.clear(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START);
                constraintMap.clear(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                constraintMap.applyTo(constraintLayout);
                constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.START);
                constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                System.out.println(isViewExpanded());

                linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong);

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

                if (!isMapExpanded()) {
                    constraintMap.constrainHeight(R.id.map, height);
                    constraintMap.constrainWidth(R.id.map, width);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.START);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, 150);

                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.longitudeTextView, ConstraintSet.INVISIBLE, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    leftFragHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    storageAccess.logMessage("Map Layout Expanded");
                    setMapExpanded(true);
                    System.out.println("Map Fragment Expanded");
                } else {
                    constraintMap.constrainHeight(R.id.map, 850);
                    constraintMap.constrainWidth(R.id.map, 890);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.START);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, 24);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, 150);


                    linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    leftFragHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    storageAccess.logMessage("Map Layout Collapse");
                    setMapExpanded(false);
                    System.out.println("Map Fragment Collapse");
                }

                constraintMap.applyTo(constraintLayout);

                break;
```

Comment: did you try `setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Comment: Yes try but still it’s not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to workaround. I am setting Linearlayout constraint to out of the screen so it is no more visible and to get back setting default constrain programmatically.

The thing I did is add set constraint to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"` programmatically when click on expand button.(When it expanding)

Then set the default constraint and margin programmatically when it collapses.

```
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
```

Here is the code for the solution

```
case R.id.expandMapBtn:
                mVib.vibrate(50);
                storageAccess.logMessage("Expand button click");
                expandMapBtn.startAnimation(myAnim);
                constraintMap.clone(constraintLayout);
                constraintMap.clear(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START);
                constraintMap.clear(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                constraintMap.applyTo(constraintLayout);
                constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.START);
                constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);

                constraintMap.setAlpha(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong,100);
                System.out.println(isViewExpanded());

                linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong);

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

                if (!isMapExpanded()) {
                    constraintMap.constrainHeight(R.id.map, height);
                    constraintMap.constrainWidth(R.id.map, width);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.START);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, 150);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);

                    linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    leftFragHolder.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    storageAccess.logMessage("Map Layout Expanded");
                    setMapExpanded(true);
                    System.out.println("Map Fragment Expanded");
                } else {
                    constraintMap.constrainHeight(R.id.map, 850);
                    constraintMap.constrainWidth(R.id.map, 890);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.START);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
                    constraintMap.connect(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.id.main_fragment_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.START, 24);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.map, ConstraintSet.TOP, 150);
//                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong, ConstraintSet.TOP, 75);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 25);
                    constraintMap.setMargin(R.id.linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong, ConstraintSet.START, 24);

                    linearLayoutRoamIOLatLong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    leftFragHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    storageAccess.logMessage("Map Layout Collapse");
                    setMapExpanded(false);
                    System.out.println("Map Fragment Collapse");
                }

                constraintMap.applyTo(constraintLayout);

                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used LayoutParams like this to hide elements that came one after the other horizontally:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_visible = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutToBeVisible.setLayoutParams(params_visible);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params_invisible = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutToBeInvisible.setLayoutParams(params_invisible);
```

First parameter of LayoutParams is width and the second is height.

Answer (score 0):

Cover your fragment xml part within a `FrameLayout` and then in Java code call setVisibility() on that FrameLayout object.

Update:

Inorder to hide your views that are stored under your viewgroup i.e. linearlayout, surround your linearlayout with Framelayout as parent.

Comment: I don't want to hide the map I would like to hide the linear layout which contains all text views.